# Change a font programmatically

Tags: c#

C# doesn't like the following code:

```
private void btnSizeRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnSizeRandom.Font.Bold = true;
  btnother.Font.Bold = false;
}
```

Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instances of `Font` are immutable. You need to construct a new `Font` and assign it to the `Font` property. The `Font` class has various constructors for this purpose; they copy another instance and change the style in the process.

Comment: +1 And just to round out the great answer: btnSizeRandom.Font = new Font(btnSizeRandom.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Additionally, you need: 

    new system.Drawing.Font(btnSizeRandom.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

Answer (score 11):

```
    private static Font ChangeBoldStyle(Font org, bool bold) {
        FontStyle style = org.Style;
        if (bold) style |= FontStyle.Bold;
        else style &= ~FontStyle.Bold;
        return new Font(org, style);
    }
```