# C# - How do you remove italic styling from text in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Here is my code for styling selected text in richtextbox to italic. However, if the selected text is italic, how can I remove that styling?

```
    private void btnitalic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var italictext = this.ActiveControl as RichTextBox;
        if (italictext != null)
        {
            italictext.SelectionFont = new Font(italictext.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set/Unset Italic in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977157/set-unset-italic-in-richtextbox)

Comment: @ShakirAhamed Thanks. Your suggestion works.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way you first formal all selected text before convert it to italic:

```
if (italictext != null)
        {
            italictext.SelectionFont = new Font(italictext.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            italictext.SelectionFont = new Font(italictext.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        }
```